# Truffle Struct Test How To Call

Tags: truffle, remix, truffle-test, solidity-0.8.x

how to call struct properties in truffle test ? for public variables we can use .call() but i cant figure out how to do with struct properties

how to access properties of struct ?
with any other public variable we can do :

await contractInstance.variableName.call()

how to do that with struct properties?

```
struct Info{
      uint price
      uint discount
}

Info public Sample1
{
      uint price: 100
      uint discount: 10
}

Info public Sample2
{
      uint price: 200
      uint discount: 20
}
```

how do i get the value for Sample2.price ?

Answer (score 0):

from the [doc](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.14/contracts.html?highlight=getters#getter-functions)

> **Getter Functions**
> The compiler automatically creates getter functions for all public
> state variables.

in your case the compiler generates a getter function for Sample1 and Sample2

so you can access your state variables on the following way

```
    const sample1 = await contractInstance.Sample1();
    console.log("price", sample1.price);
```

---

and take a look at the naming styles in the [doc](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.14/style-guide.html?highlight=variable%20names#local-and-state-variable-names)

> Use mixedCase. Examples: totalSupply, remainingSupply, balancesOf, creatorAddress, isPreSale, tokenExchangeRate.

you should use mixedCase to name your state variables